# Unity3D Asset Bundle Animator Dependencies

Tags: ios, animation, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

**Problem:**

While packing an Animation Controller I am getting a ton of unwanted dependencies.

**Description:**

*So I have a animation controller loaded up with animations and parameters. These animations are all separated into their own FBX's and make use of Unity's Humanoid Animation type, taking their avatar off of the base character rig. As expected, but not desired ( the base rig fbx is added and it's shaders etc ) despite the fact that they are going to be packed in the actual application. This is not my biggest issue.*

**My biggest issue** is that every single texture used on all of my various characters that make use of these humanoid animations are being packed into my asset bundle.

**Things I have tried:**

-Looking through all the animations to see if they manipulate textures

-Checking to make sure all the textures have no 'Asset labels' that designate their packing.

-Selected the dependencies of the Animation controller. Which resulted in the base rigs materials / textures as well as the humanoid animations added (shown as game objects). This is everything I expect to be in the asset bundle, but it packs all textures / materials in my project instead.

[image]

If anyone has any ideas, or suggestions on tests I can do, that would be appreciated.

******************UPDATE********************

I think I have this all wrong. (just judging by the small size of my bundle) When I pack for iOS / Android, I believe the unity editor is switching platforms, as if I went to build setting -> switch platform, and re-compressing textures not packing them, then the asset bundle manager is taking from those files compressed for their respective platforms. It seems strange that it would have to do this for all assets. If anyone has insight on this I would be appreciative.

Update -> Switching platforms before building asset bundles for that platforms removes most all of the packing time, I'm assuming the above assertion is correct. Still looking for documentation

Comment: Hey, could you share a picture of your hierarchy and the asset folder(1 page)?